# Need to see the instanced objects in a .net application

Tags: wpf, apex

I'm struggling with a Wpf application, using the Apex MVVM framework.
I suspect instantiation problems.
How can I see the instanced objects in the running app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example use the [Windows Debugger (WinDbg)](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/download-windbg) and its `!dumpheap –stat` command to list the objects on the heap.

Please refer to Tess Ferrandez's blog post for more information:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2005/11/25/dumpheap-stat-explained-debugging-net-leaks/

Comment: I have VS 2013, so (apparently) I have WinDbg installed. But... how can I start it?

Comment: windgb.exe should be located under C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86 (or C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64 if you are using the 64-bit version) after you have installed the SDK from the link I supplied.

Comment: Sorry, but the command "!dumpheap stat" causes an error as follow "0:010> !dumpheap stat
No export dumpheap found"

Comment: Dod you load the sos extension? https://netmatze.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/using-windbg-exe-and-sos-dll-to-debug-a-net-4-0-application/

Comment: Thank you. I will take the advice for future needs. The case I was trying to debug was an error from my code. Using Apex, when the XAML code creates the ViewModel, the executor is in charge of instantiating all base classes. My error was calling base() again in the constructor of my viewmodel class. Solved.